# Pyhton for loop "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

python for loop "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('F:\\work\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

Content =["listtext1","listtext2","listtext3","listtext4"]
for i in range(4):
    time.sleep(7)
    url = "https://quillbot.com/"
    driver.get(url)
    Text_block = driver.find_element(By.ID, "inputText")
    Text_block.send_keys(Content[i])# Change (fetch from Search_list)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: yes please check again i updated

Comment: i am getting this error " selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few fixes to your code:

1. Inserted [user_agent](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) (it will come in handy with other experiments on selenium)
2. inserted a [web driver manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) to run selenium on all operating systems.
3. You have to accept cookies before you can interact with the page.
4. removed unnecessary sleep.

This is the result, code tested:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

# add user_agent
user_agent = "user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36]"
options.add_argument(user_agent)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)  # to use over all systems
browser_delay = 2  # set if based on your connection and device speed

Content =["listtext1","listtext2","listtext3","listtext4"]
for i in range(len(Content)):
    url = "https://quillbot.com/"
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        cookie_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, browser_delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler')))
        cookie_btn.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        pass  # it's a timeout or element just clicked

    Text_block = driver.find_element(By.ID, "inputText")
    Text_block.send_keys(Content[i])  # Change (fetch from Search_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of sending those texts into that textbox, based on your existing code and how you defined waits:

```
[....]
content =["listtext1","listtext2","listtext3","listtext4"]

for i in content:
    driver.get('https://quillbot.com/')
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
        print('accepted cookies')
    except Exception as e:
        print('no cookie button!')
    text_block = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "inputText")))
    text_block.send_keys(i)
    print('sent', i)
    t.sleep(5)
```

See Selenium documentation at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/